# Help - construct Hermite interpolation polynomial

Tags: numerical-methods

Construct Hermite interpolation polynomial if:
$ f(1)=0, f'(1)=3, f''(1)=4, f(3)=1, f''(3)=4 $.
Can you give me some tips how to do this task?

Comment: The principle is explained here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation ... It will be a bit of a grind ! ... Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

$a+bx+cx^2+dx^3+ex^4$

a+b+c+d+e=0,

b+2c+3d+4e=3,

2c+6d+12e=4,

a+3b+9c+27d+81e=1,

2c+18d+108e=4

$49/16-14x+(133/8)x^2-(13/2)x^3+(13/16)x^4$

Comment: do it formally, do it the right way, not just like I did it